# Debug Drupal with Ubuntu 10 & PHP5.2

Tags: php, debugging, drupal, xdebug, zend-studio

hey
im trying to debug drupal with xdebug , here is the system info:

PHP Version 5.2.10-2ubuntu6

Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 10.04.1 LTS
Release:        10.04
Codename:       lucid

the thing is that im working via local network so my machine is like 192.168.1.100 and the server is 192.168.1.101

is there a way to debug it using xdebug ? i can use zend studio 8 or eclipse pdt or whatever software you can recommend to do this
please help me

Answer (score 0):

I once setup the Drupal debugging environment with xdebug under windows. 
 Not sure whether it applies to Ubuntu as well. But you can take a look and try. Don't forget to post your feedback here (or directly reply to my blog there:).   
Here's the [link](http://tumer.wordpress.com/2010/11/04/drupal-6-debugging-with-eclipse-php-and-xdebug-on-win-xp/)

**Update:** got it working on my Ubuntu 10.10. Basically the steps in the above links are fine, except you might need to build the xdebug your self, which is quite well documented in its documentation.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is quite easy to set up if you follow the xdebug instructions. Just make sure that the xdebug port is available over the network (in your xdebug.ini) and that it is enabled and it will work as if it were installed locally.